# how this function read text into a struct?

Tags: c++, iostream

I am trying to understand what exactly the following function is doing. It is used to read a text file into a **struct**, called `AEntry`, which only contains four ints.

The file contains a list of lines. Each line holds four ints delimited with **spaces** (or **tab**).

when this function is called, a line of `istream` and a `AEntry` `struct` are passed in.

My question is how the delimitors, spacess or tabs, are filtered out? or my understanding is wrong.

```
istream& operator>>( istream &stream, AEntry& val )
{
    stream >> val.kv;
    stream >> val.col;
    stream >> val.bo;
    stream >> val.Offset;
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: Whitespace characters are extracted by built-in `operator>>` overloads. How these behave is explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedInputFunction).

Comment: This is not a C question.

Comment: I couldn't post this question until I add C tag. Only C++ tag is NOT meet the "quality standard". I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're filtered out because that's the behavior of the default overloads of `istream::operator>>`. They stop at whitespace and discard it instead of incorporating it into the extracted output.

Comment: +1 .. and skip whitespace at the onset of the next formatted extraction (manipulater `skipws` not withstanding).

Comment: @WhozCraig True... So many slight details. The link Jrok provided in his comment was a good read for me.

Comment: how about tabs "\t" ? The same as spaces?

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA No, tabs aren't the same as spaces, but they are in the "whitespace" character class.

Comment: I mean are tabs treated the same as space in default overloads of istream::operator>>?